# Apache2 combine RewriteRules

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I have about a hundred `RewriteRule`s in my .htaccess, such as the following ones:

```
RewriteRule ^cars-and-([%a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ https://example.com/cars-and-$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^cars-and-([%a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/0[/]{0,1}$ https://example.com/cars-and-$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^cars-and-([%a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([0-9]+)$ /pathto/search.php?city=$1&page=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^cars-and-([%a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ /pathto/search.php?city=$1&page=0 [L]
```

I now want to add support for AMP pages. Simply adding a `.amp` end to the URL should display the AMP version of the page.

I could create 100 additional `RewriteRule`s to cover all those cases with the `.amp` ending, but am wondering if there is an easier way to proceed?

Is there a way to add a single RewriteRule when .amp is detected that adds a `amp=1` parameter and then falls back to the existing rewrites (without dropping the `amp=1` parameter)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like that on top of your existing rules:

`RewriteRule (.+)(\.amp)$ $1?amp=1`

Then add the `QSA` flag to your existing ones.

Note that you have to avoid the `[L]` flag on that new rule so it goes through the rest of them.